# syslog error: home kernel:...audit:. type=1400 audit: apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="docker-default"

Tags: kernel, docker

Ubuntu server 18.04LTS Docker version 18.03.1-ce

Good day, over the last 4 days I've been getting the following error in syslog. There's no noticeable operational degradation.

Appreciate feedback on what it is or what it means and potential solution

```
May 19 14:26:19 home kernel: [18579.964715] audit: type=1400 audit(1526725579.573:16810): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="docker-default" pid=18660 comm="python" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it.  My problem was that I have a docker container with the following in the run command.

```
--cap-add SYS_PTRACE
```

apparmor is denying the container that access to the host by default.  I resolved the issue by adding the following to my docker run command:

```
--security-opt apparmor:unconfined
```